# Script works on Windows, but not on Linux (Syntax Error)

Tags: python, linux, windows, raspberry-pi

I created a python script on my PC (Windows 10) with Python 3.6.2 and it works like a charm :

```
for i in range(101):
    time.sleep(0.015)
    print('Starting ..... [%d%%]\r'%i, end="")
else :
   print('\n Ready.')
```

I recently got a raspberry pi running on raspbian with Python 3.4.2 and when I try to run the exact same script from the command I got an error:

```
print('Starting ..... [%d%%]\r'%i, end="")
                                      ^
Syntax Error: invalid Syntax (The error seems to be the equal sign)
```

Any idea? Maybe Python version? Maybe something else?

**EDIT :**

Indeed, @Steven Rumbalski is right. Raspbian automaticaly install 2 versions of Python : 2.7.9 and 3.4.2
So I just had to put "python3 myscript.py" instead of "python myscript.py" (or, as @Toandd said : use a shebang line) thank you very much for the help.

Comment: That's the error you would get with Python 2.7 where `print` is a statement and not a function.  I'll bet if you go to the command line and run `python -V` you will show Python 2.7.  It's possible that you have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 on your raspberry pi.  Sometimes python 3 is differentiated as `python3` and Python 2 is just `python`, but I don't know what the converion is for raspberry pi.

Comment: If you find you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed, you may find this question on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange site helpful: [I want to switch between versions 2 & 3 of Python. Both are installed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42813/i-want-to-switch-between-versions-2-3-of-python-both-are-installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same idea with @Steven Rumbalski. And to resolve this issue, you should add following line at the top of python script (shebang line).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Or you can run "python3 script.py" if you don't want to add shebang line.

Comment: Use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.